# Calculate readmission rate

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate both 30-days and 180-days readmission rate for patients that visited the Emergency department(ED) in 2015, but I'm not quite sure how can I do that.

My data frame looks something like this:

```
Visit # |Patient # | Admission Date | Discharge date
   1       1         2015/01/01        2015/01/02
   2       2         2015/01/01        2015/01/01         
   3       3         2015/01/01        2015/01/02
   4       1         2015/01/09        2015/01/09                                       
   5       2         2015/04/01        2015/04/05
   6       1         2015/05/01        2015/05/01
```

I was hoping to have two additional columns with a binary variable [0,1] indicating whether the patient was readmitted within 30 days and/or 60 days. 
In the example above Patient 1 comes to the ED 3 times, 2 in January and once more in May, thus I'd hope to have readmit30 = 1 and readmit180 = 1. Patient 2 comes 2 times, once in January and once in April, thus readmit30 = 0 and readmit60 = 1.
Sample solution:

```
Visit # |Patient #| Admission Date | Discharge date | readmit30 | readmit180
   1       1        2015/01/01        2015/01/02        1          1
   2       2        2015/01/01        2015/01/01        0          1 
   3       3        2015/01/01        2015/01/02        0          0
   4       1        2015/01/09        2015/01/09        1          1                               
   5       2        2015/04/01        2015/04/05        0          1
   6       1        2015/05/01        2015/05/01        1          1
```

My data set has approximately 2000 visits with approximately 1500 patients..
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: welcome to SO.  a reproducible data set would be very helpful for this problem.  It sounds like you're asking for a rolling self-join on patient id and admission date, where new admission date is within 30 or 60 days of the old discharge date.  This is pretty easy to do in `data.table` but your options in base R will probably require looping over rows.

Comment: Do you mean `Readmit180`? You ask originally for 180-day readmit then refer back to 60-day readmit.

Comment: yep I did mean readmit180, I just edited my initial problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I actually do this quite a bit: the best method I have found is using `data.table`. Let's suppose your data is saved as `ds`, then:

```
s <- read.table(text = "Visit Patient Admission Discharge
1 1 2015/01/01 2015/01/02
2 2 2015/01/01 2015/01/01         
3 3 2015/01/01 2015/01/02
4 1 2015/01/09 2015/01/09                                       
5 2 2015/04/01 2015/04/05
6 1 2015/05/01 2015/05/01", header = T, sep = "")

s$Admission <- as.POSIXct(s$Admission, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
s$Discharge <- as.POSIXct(s$Discharge, format = "%Y/%m/%d")

ds <- data.table(s)

setkey(ds, Patient, Admission)
ds <- ds[ , Daydiff := as.numeric(difftime(shift(Admission, n = 1L, fill = 999, type = "lead"), Discharge)), 
          by = "Patient"][ ,':='(Readmit30 = ifelse(abs(Daydiff) <= 30, 1, 0), 
                                 Readmit180= ifelse(abs(Daydiff) <= 180, 1, 0),
                                 Daydiff   = NULL)]
```

This results in

```
> ds
   Visit Patient  Admission  Discharge      Daydiff Readmit30 Readmit180
1:     1       1 2015-01-01 2015-01-02      7.00000         1          1
2:     4       1 2015-01-09 2015-01-09    111.95833         0          1
3:     6       1 2015-05-01 2015-05-01 -16556.15510         0          0
4:     2       2 2015-01-01 2015-01-01     89.95833         0          1
5:     5       2 2015-04-01 2015-04-05 -16530.15510         0          0
6:     3       3 2015-01-01 2015-01-02 -16437.19677         0          0
```

Please keep in mind though, this only determines which records have a subsequent 30-day or 180-day readmit, and not which are actually the 30-day or 180-day readmit.

Comment: Thank you @akash87, your code does exactly what I needed. I appreciate you taking the time