# readmission rates in R

Tags: r

I would like to build upon this question that was asked several months back
[readmission question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508585/calculate-readmission-rate)

I have some patient admission data that I would like to have r check the patients admission status to see if it is a readmission or not.  If the patient status is that of inpatient, I would like to look back 30 days to see if there is another inpatient encounter.  If there is another inpatient encounter I would like to populate a 30 day column to say yes, otherwise populate no if it does not.  I have some example data as to what I am needing.  Each patient has a unique MRN number that never changes but can have many encounter numbers for each visit.  "df2" is what I am looking to create after evaluating "df".  Any help is appreciated.  I am not sure if the previous post would use a similar setup or not.

```
csn <- c("11111","22222","33333","44444","55555","66666","77777")
mrn <- c("44322","81433","56311","44322","55121","61776","44322")
admit_date <- c("2017-02-01","2017-02-02","2017-02-04","2017-02-10","2017-02-12","2017-02-14","2017-02-18")
disch_date <- c("2017-02-03","2017-02-04","2017-02-04","2017-02-10","2017-02-16","2017-02-14","2017-02-25")
encounter_type <-c("Inpatient","Inpatient","Observation","ER","Inpatient","Observation","Inpatient")
readmission_30day <- c("no","no","no","no","no","no","yes")
df <- data.frame(csn,mrn,admit_date,disch_date,encounter_type)
df2 <- data.frame(csn,mrn,admit_date,disch_date,encounter_type,readmission_30day)

df
df2
```

Comment: It looks like you have the same question as the one you link, and a very similar data structure. Did you try the solution posted there? How did it go? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've got an answer for you that uses the dplyr package. I'll try to explain what's going on but you might have to read up a little bit. If you don't know the pipe-operator (%>%) - just read it as a "then".

```
# we need 2 libraries
library(tidyverse) # this provides several useful packages
library(lubridate) # this lets you deal more easily with dates

# first, we create a table that contains the csn of the relevant cases
# and the days since last admission

parkDf <- df %>% # we take our data frame
    mutate(admit_date = as_date(admit_date)) %>% # turn the dates into date format
    filter(encounter_type == "Inpatient") %>% # filter out cases with "Inpatient"
    arrange(mrn, admit_date) %>% # sort them first by mrn and then by admit_date
    group_by(mrn) %>% # group them by mrn so we can for each patient...
    mutate(daysSinceLastAdmit = admit_date - lag(admit_date)) %>% # ...get the days since last admit
    mutate(daysSinceLastAdmit = as.integer(daysSinceLastAdmit)) %>% # turn this into an integer
    ungroup() %>% # ungroup it (must be done - don't ask)
    select(csn, daysSinceLastAdmit) # and keep only these two columns

# now we left-join this to our original dataframe
df %>%
    left_join(parkDf, by = "csn") %>%
    mutate(readmission_30day = if_else(is.na(daysSinceLastAdmit), "no", "yes")) %>% # create the wanted variable
    select(-daysSinceLastAdmit) # and remove the unwanted one
```

You can read more about the used functions if you google "R for data science" or "r4ds" - this is a book written by Hadley Wickham which is a great author. If you don't know what a left join is, just google "sql left join". It's basically: take what's on the right (our newly created dataframe), add its information to what's on the left (original dataframe) and do so by matching a column that exists in both dataframes (by).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Gregory, Thanks a lot.  My real dataset had a discharge date that I did not include in my example one, but I was able to take what you gave me and calculate the difference in admit date and previous discharge date to get the 30 day readmission.  Thanks again for your time and input.

Comment: @Gregory Can you look at this question I asked.  I tried to blend the answer you gave on this with that question, but I am not getting the results I am looking for.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835617/i-need-to-create-a-new-column-that-sums-the-amount-of-instances-a-particular-obs)