# I need to create a new column that sums the amount of instances a particular observation happened

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set of hospital visits and I need to tally utilization of emergency room visits that happened in a certain time frame.  The code below mimics what my dataset looks like.  The hospital account is a unique number for that encounter and the MRN number is unique to the patient.  One patient can have many hospital accounts but only one MRN.

```
hosp.acct <- sample(10000:30000, 20, replace = F)
MRN <- c(sample(40000:60000, 6, replace = F),61212,sample(40000:60000, 6, 
replace = F),61212,sample(40000:60000, 5, replace = F),61212)
set.seed(41)   
admit.date <- Sys.Date() + sort(sample(1:30, 20))
disch.date <- admit.date
disch.date[15] <- disch.date[15] + 2
disch.date[20] <- disch.date[20] + 3
admit.type <- c(rep("ED",14), "Inpatient",rep("ED",4),"Inpatient")
patients <- data.frame(hosp.acct,MRN,admit.date,disch.date,admit.type)
```

The data looks like this

```
   hosp.acct   MRN admit.date disch.date admit.type
1      12265 43685 2018-02-17 2018-02-17         ED
2      26536 58422 2018-02-18 2018-02-18         ED
3      15569 59675 2018-02-20 2018-02-20         ED
4      24261 50523 2018-02-21 2018-02-21         ED
5      27088 42435 2018-02-23 2018-02-23         ED
6      20027 49420 2018-02-28 2018-02-28         ED
7      17513 61212 2018-03-01 2018-03-01         ED
8      15140 49624 2018-03-02 2018-03-02         ED
9      19561 56721 2018-03-03 2018-03-03         ED
10     19380 53224 2018-03-05 2018-03-05         ED
11     22578 54514 2018-03-06 2018-03-06         ED
12     21358 59142 2018-03-07 2018-03-07         ED
13     24919 53604 2018-03-08 2018-03-08         ED
14     29646 61212 2018-03-09 2018-03-09         ED
15     26191 44328 2018-03-10 2018-03-12  Inpatient
16     25820 56705 2018-03-11 2018-03-11         ED
17     21598 41922 2018-03-12 2018-03-12         ED
18     13708 43277 2018-03-13 2018-03-13         ED
19     29753 46511 2018-03-14 2018-03-14         ED
20     28573 61212 2018-03-17 2018-03-20  Inpatient
```

My goal is to have R count ER visits the patient had within a specific timeframe (ie 30 days) if there admit type was "Inpatient". The goal result would look like this.

```
   hosp.acct   MRN admit.date disch.date admit.type ed.visits
1      12265 43685 2018-02-17 2018-02-17         ED         0 << Maybe NA HERE on the ED observations
2      26536 58422 2018-02-18 2018-02-18         ED         0
3      15569 59675 2018-02-20 2018-02-20         ED         0
4      24261 50523 2018-02-21 2018-02-21         ED         0
5      27088 42435 2018-02-23 2018-02-23         ED         0
6      20027 49420 2018-02-28 2018-02-28         ED         0
7      17513 61212 2018-03-01 2018-03-01         ED         0
8      15140 49624 2018-03-02 2018-03-02         ED         0
9      19561 56721 2018-03-03 2018-03-03         ED         0
10     19380 53224 2018-03-05 2018-03-05         ED         0
11     22578 54514 2018-03-06 2018-03-06         ED         0
12     21358 59142 2018-03-07 2018-03-07         ED         0
13     24919 53604 2018-03-08 2018-03-08         ED         0
14     29646 61212 2018-03-09 2018-03-09         ED         0
15     26191 44328 2018-03-10 2018-03-12  Inpatient         0  <<Only the inpatient encounters check previous ED visits
16     25820 56705 2018-03-11 2018-03-11         ED         0
17     21598 41922 2018-03-12 2018-03-12         ED         0
18     13708 43277 2018-03-13 2018-03-13         ED         0
19     29753 46511 2018-03-14 2018-03-14         ED         0
20     28573 61212 2018-03-17 2018-03-20  Inpatient         2 << This patient had two ED visits in last 30 days
```

I think dplyr is probably the tool to use but beyond arranging and grouping them by MRN and date, I do not know how to have dplyr count up how many ed visits happened 30 days prior to current inpatient visit.

Thank you,

Brad

Thanks to everyones contribution. With the help of all, I was able to gather ideas and put together what I believe works.  If anyone sees problems, please chime in.  My solution is below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) 
patients.temp <- patients %>%
    mutate(admit.date = as_date(admit.date)) %>%
    filter(admit.type %in% c("Inpatient","ED")) %>%
    arrange(MRN,admit.date) %>%
    group_by(MRN) %>%
    mutate(ED.30day = map(admit.date, ~sum(admit.type == "ED" & between(admit.date, . - 30, . - 0))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the results I needed with the help of dplyr.  Below is what I used to get the results I was looking for.  Thanks to everyone who contributed.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) 
patients.temp <- patients %>%
    mutate(admit.date = as_date(admit.date)) %>%
    filter(admit.type %in% c("Inpatient","ED")) %>%
    arrange(MRN,admit.date) %>%
    group_by(MRN) %>%
    mutate(ED.30day = map(admit.date, ~sum(admit.type == "ED" & between(admit.date, . - 30, . - 0))))
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Here's one option: 1 - create a new column with a last.visit column that takes each patient's most recent visit.
2 - filter for anything within 30 days prior to that last.visit.
3 - add a column that counts the number of ED visits.

```
patients %>%
  group_by(MRN) %>%
  mutate(last.visit = max(admit.date)) %>%
  filter(last.visit - 30 <= admit.date) %>%
  mutate(ed.visits = length(admit.type[admit.type == "ED"])) %>%
  arrange(desc(ed.visits))
```

**Previous answer**

Filter for the last 30 days, then add a column with the total number of ED visits:

```
patients %>%
  group_by(MRN) %>%
  filter(admit.date >= admit.date - 30) %>%
  mutate(ed.visits = length(admit.type[admit.type == "ED"])) %>%
  filter(admit.type == "Inpatient")
```

Which returns:

```
hosp.acct   MRN admit.date disch.date admit.type ed.visits
      <int> <dbl> <date>     <date>     <fct>          <int>
1     24425 49799 2018-03-10 2018-03-12 Inpatient          0
2     15970 61212 2018-03-17 2018-03-20 Inpatient          2
```

Or, if you leave off the last 'filter', you'll get:

```
hosp.acct   MRN admit.date disch.date admit.type ed.visits
       <int> <dbl> <date>     <date>     <fct>          <int>
 1     14292 61212 2018-03-01 2018-03-01 ED                 2
 2     17509 61212 2018-03-09 2018-03-09 ED                 2
 3     15970 61212 2018-03-17 2018-03-20 Inpatient          2
 4     29047 46473 2018-02-17 2018-02-17 ED                 1
```

Either way, it doesn't solve the problem of not tallying the number of ED visits for ED patients.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I should be able to work with that.  If the visit is an "ED" visit, then I do not not need to return a count in that column.  I may do a left join on your first result with the original dataset to get what I need.  Thank you.  I was able to take what you did and add a couple of lines to get what I needed.  I will edit my post to show what I did.

Comment: Slight problem,  When I add push MRN 61212's inpatient visit out by 30 days and make it 4/17/2018, then I still get 2 as the result when I should get 0.  Havi, if you have suggestions that would be great.  I still think I need to incorporate lag into the mix.

Comment: Brad, I added a new column called last.visit, which gives the patient's most recent visit, then filtered for anything within 30 days of that, like this:  mutate(last.visit = max(admit.date)) %>%filter(last.visit - 30 <= admit.date). I'll add to answer.