# Calculating readmission rate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am fairly new to Python and I am trying to calculate if a patient was readmitted to the hospital within 30 days or not.

The data is in the form of Pandas dataframe with columns for Patient Id, Arrival Date, Departure Date and Status (Discharged, Admitted, Did Not Wait). The question is similar to this past question with same requirements but I need the code in Python.

[Calculate readmission rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508585/calculate-readmission-rate)

I only need one column of readmission (30 day readmission status). Any help in the code's translation is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

@ anky_91 Please do correct me if I am wrong in my understanding. Some random examples my data[ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caUeT.png) [ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7ixe.png) [ex3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otf1U.png)

Comment: Is this just a bump on an old question?

Comment: Not exactly. Yes the question is similar but the programming language (i.e. R ) was used for the old question. If possible, I needed a answer in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one also ( Don't know why upper one was giving false readmission flags for me):
After sorting on visit_start_date

```
visits_pandas_df.groupby('PatientId').apply(lambda x: (((x['visit_start_date'].shift(-1)-x['visit_end_date']).dt.days.shift(1).le(30)) ).astype(int)).values
```

Visits having only difference of one day are not counted in readmissions. So you will also need to check in your logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below:

```
df.groupby('Patient').apply(lambda x : (x['Admission Date'].\
    shift(-1)-x['Discharge date']).dt.days.le(30).astype(int)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Full code**:

Considering the df looks like:

```
   Visit  Patient Admission Date Discharge date
0      1        1     2015-01-01     2015-01-02
1      2        2     2015-01-01     2015-01-01
2      3        3     2015-01-01     2015-01-02
3      4        1     2015-01-09     2015-01-09
4      5        2     2015-04-01     2015-04-05
5      6        1     2015-05-01     2015-05-01


df[['Admission Date','Discharge date']] = df[['Admission Date','Discharge date']].\
                                                apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
df = df.sort_values(['Patient','Admission Date']) #Thanks @Jondiedoop

df['Readmit30']=df.groupby('Patient').apply(lambda x : (x['Admission Date'].\
shift(-1)-x['Discharge date']).dt.days.le(30).astype(int)).reset_index(0).drop('Patient',1)
print(df)


   Visit  Patient Admission Date Discharge date  Readmit30
0      1        1     2015-01-01     2015-01-02      1
3      4        1     2015-01-09     2015-01-09      0
5      6        1     2015-05-01     2015-05-01      0
1      2        2     2015-01-01     2015-01-01      0
4      5        2     2015-04-01     2015-04-05      0
2      3        3     2015-01-01     2015-01-02      0
```

Comment: The code runs but the some values in Readmit30 are not accurate as many patients are wrongly marked as readmitted. Thank you

Comment: Sure. My original dataset is different than the one in the question but here are some values. Please check my edited question

Comment: in the other solution and mine the Daydiff  is exactly the same if you just execute `df.groupby('Patient').apply(lambda x : (x['Admission Date'].shift(-1)-x['Discharge date']).dt.days).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: This time it replaced 0 with NaN and 1 with 0

Comment: Note that for this solution to work, a *sorted* dataframe is required (otherwise the shift makes no sense). You can either sort first, or state the requirement explicitly.

Comment: facepalm, i had sorted the df based on patient, forgot to post that line. many thanks @Jondiedoop. :)

Comment: Don't just sort on `Patient` though, also sort on `AdmissionDate` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ anky_91 & @Jondiedoop. Works like a charm!!