# How to mark episodes in which patient will be readmitted in 30-days?

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a dataset with patients episodes.
Every patient has its own patientPersonalNumber.
Inpatient episode has admission and discharge date.
I need to mark in new variable (with TRUE, or with 1) all episodes that patient in that episode will be readmitted within 30 days.

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
admission <- c("06/23/2013", "06/30/2013", "07/12/2013","06/24/2013","06/28/2013","06/29/2013","06/23/2013","06/24/2013","06/24/2013","07/02/2013","07/09/2013","06/24/2013","09/08/2013","07/22/2014")
discharge<- c("06/25/2013", "07/03/2014", "07/17/2014","06/30/2013","06/30/2013","07/02/2013","06/29/2013","06/29/2013","06/27/2013","07/05/2013","07/12/2013","06/28/2013","10/12/2013","08/01/2014")
admission.date <- mdy(admission)
discharge.date <- mdy(discharge)
patientPersonalNumber<-c("001","002","004","005","006","007","008","009","010", "005","005","011","005", "004")
df<-data.frame(patientPersonalNumber,admission.date,discharge.date)
df
       
       patientPersonalNumber admission.date discharge.date
1                    001     2013-06-23     2013-06-25
2                    002     2013-06-30     2014-07-03
3                    004     2014-07-12     2014-07-17
4                    005     2013-06-24     2013-06-30
5                    006     2013-06-28     2013-06-30
6                    007     2013-06-29     2013-07-02
7                    008     2013-06-23     2013-06-29
8                    009     2013-06-24     2013-06-29
9                    010     2013-06-24     2013-06-27
10                   005     2013-07-02     2013-07-05
11                   005     2013-07-09     2013-07-12
12                   011     2013-06-24     2013-06-28
13                   005     2013-09-08     2013-10-12
14                   004     2014-07-22     2014-08-01

So I have to mark lines (3,4,10) as true.
#4 Patient 005 discharged 2013-06-30 was admitted 2013-07-02
#10 Patient 005 discharged 2013-07-05 was admitted 2013-07-09
#3 Patient 004 discharged 2013-06-30 was admitted 2013-07-22

I appreciate any help.

#origianl data were edit
```

Comment: Sort by patient id and admission date, create a new variable next.admission.date (perhaps with the dplyr lag function), then test whether next.admission.date - discharge date is between 0 and 30. There are some pitfalls to be aware of, such as: can one hospitalization be counted as both an index and readmission? We always followed the CMS methodology when they were punishing Medicare-reimbursed hospitals for excess readmissions.

Comment: There's a data.table solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508585/calculate-readmission-rate

Comment: @BillO'Brien, thanks. I will check it. I could not find it by search. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest using the index hospitalization as the unit of analysis. Prefix the variables for clarity, e.g. index.admit.date, index.disch.date, rdm.admit.date, rdm.disch.date. It will make calculation of readmission rates a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would go with something like this:

```
require(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  arrange(patientPersonalNumber, admission.date) %>% 
  group_by(patientPersonalNumber) %>% 
  mutate(re.admin = (lag(discharge.date) + 30) >= admission.date) %>% 
  mutate(re.admin = ifelse(is.na(re.admin), FALSE, re.admin ))



# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   patientPersonalNumber [10]
   patientPersonalNumber admission.date discharge.date re.admin
   <chr>                 <date>         <date>         <lgl>   
 1 001                   2013-06-23     2013-06-25     FALSE   
 2 002                   2013-06-30     2014-07-03     FALSE   
 3 004                   2013-07-22     2014-08-01     FALSE   
 4 004                   2014-07-12     2014-07-17     TRUE    
 5 005                   2013-06-24     2013-06-30     FALSE   
 6 005                   2013-07-02     2013-07-05     TRUE    
 7 005                   2013-07-09     2013-07-12     TRUE    
 8 005                   2013-09-08     2013-10-12     FALSE   
 9 006                   2013-06-28     2013-06-30     FALSE   
10 007                   2013-06-29     2013-07-02     FALSE   
11 008                   2013-06-23     2013-06-29     FALSE   
12 009                   2013-06-24     2013-06-29     FALSE   
13 010                   2013-06-24     2013-06-27     FALSE   
14 011                   2013-06-24     2013-06-28     FALSE
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks. However, it seems to me that the in the pair this code marked second episode. It is beneficial, also.  However, my focus is only on the fist episode.

Comment: for 005, only the first two should be true. #5 discharged 2013-06-30 and admitied 2013-07-02 and #6 discharged 2013-07-05 and admitied 2013-07-09